# AWS Quicksight - MySQL UNION from multiple databases

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I'm using AWS Quicksight for an Analytics dashboard and I have multiple databases that have the same tables. I then set a Data Source for each database. Now, I've been trying to create a Data Set for a table, let's say "products" table, which should be a UNION of all the "products" tables of all the databases.

So far, I've only been able to combine data from those databases using the UI to do a JOIN. However, for the Analysis I'm trying to create, I'll be needing to do a UNION. How do you do a UNION from multiple different databases in AWS Quicksight? Thanks.

Comment: You might find a better answer for this on: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Doesn't an outer join work to give a union?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL to connect in whatever way you wish. When you create a dataset, choose `use custom sql` and you will be presented with the window below, where you can then use SQL to `join`, `union` or whatever to your hearts content :)

[image]

Comment: This will only work if both DBs can be accessed from one connection. If they are 2 entirely separate instances, you can't use a single query to union them.